# How to check if my network is blocking UDP traffic?

Tags: windows, networking, android, udp

I have noticed that some applications on my phone are unable to connect when my phone is connected to my home WiFi, while they do work over 4G, even though my WiFi connection is fast and stable.

I have reason to believe(*) that UDP connections are unreliable or not working at all. Is there a good way to test this? I have access to an android phone and a Windows laptop (with windows subsystem for linux). I can connect the laptop over WiFi or ethernet to my router.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/589732/how-to-detect-if-network-is-dropping-udp-packets) similar question. The answers there require setting up a UPD server on a separate host outside of the network. Unfortunately I don't have access to such a host, unless I can set up a UDP server on my phone (how?).

(*) specifically: I reported a bug in the company I work for while working from home, and the engineering team mentioned that they see this issue on networks where UDP is blocked.

Comment: it may be the network, or it may be your router. as a generic proposition, UDP does not work as well over NAT as TCP does, because the NAT cannot concretely associate an outbound flow with an inbound one in response. as such they make inferences that provide a degree of certainty that a request/response are related. as consumer grade routers age, they tend to degrade slowly, becoming less and less reliable as they die. if you have another you can drop in, that may be a reasonable test.

Answer (score 1):

there is related question on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/970921/how-to-start-iperf3-server-in-udp-mode
in short, assuming you have two comps needed to test udp on some port. start ** iperf -s ** server on comp1 and ** iperf ** client on comp2 with ops as follow `iperf3 -u -c server.ip.address -b` 
Yes, you can use your android phone as client or as a server iperf. The only thing to install termux  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux a Linux like terminal on phone. There you can install iperf with `apt install iperf3 iperf3-static` I should note that iperf run under windows as well https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php